# How can I make my Plotly subplots use the same y-axis range?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a scatter plot with 3 subplots that share the x-axis. I want each subplot to use the same range for the y-axis, ie starting at 0. I've tried using `rangemode='tozero'`, but that doesn't work. Any insights would be much appreciated!

See https://codepen.io/kbreuer/pen/XWWqwde

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2],
  y: [2, 3, 4],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4],
  y: [3, 4, 5],
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace3 = {
  x: [3, 4, 5],
  y: [1, 2, 3],
  yaxis: 'y3',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

var layout = {
  yaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  y2axis: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  y3axis: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  grid: {
    rows: 3,
    columns: 1,
    subplots: [['xy'], ['xy2'], ['xy3']]
   },
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. There's just a minor issue with your `layout` definition.

Both `y2axis` and `y3axis` won't be recognised as I believe Plotly adopts the convention whereby it expects any additional axes to have their identifying number postfixed. In other words, what you want is:

```
var layout = {
  yaxis: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  yaxis2: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  yaxis3: {rangemode: 'tozero'},
  grid: {
    rows: 3,
    columns: 1,
    subplots: [['xy'], ['xy2'], ['xy3']]
   },
};
```